# Inserting superscript using <sup> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, superscript

I have found many posts on superscripts here but none seemed to coverwhat I require. I want to be able to store and display superscript, the field in my table is set to utf8 currently. I have a form that inserts using php, if i type the alt code for example TM alt 0153 is displays in the form field as superscript, saves in my database as superscripts and even displays as superscript too, Great! However I don't expect my users to know the alt codes for things like ™ and they also may want to enter something not allocated by alt codes. So what I was thinkg is possible getting them to use the superscript tags in the html form such as:

```
<sup>superscript</sup>
```

My database will however just store this as

```
<sup>superscript</sup>
```

I use escaoe string before inserting such as:

```
$free = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed['freeform']);
```

Anyone therefore have an idea of how I can type a sup tag into the html form and get php to insert it as superscript?

Any help or direction greatly appreciated.

Ian

**EDIT**

Try to clear up my awkwardly worded question. Basically I need a user to be able to enter any words they require as superscript in my form, and for it to save as superscript into my database.

My form and database will currenlty accept superscript values I enter using alt codes (E.G. hold alt and press 0153), but if I copy some superscript text for example from word, its just displays and stores as standard text.

Is this any clearer?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Still your question is not clear? can you state it directly what you want and what is coming right now?

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, but allowing your users to add html introduces a big security risk so you might want to rethink that.

Comment: Yes I'm with @jeroen that'll cause `SQL Injection`

Comment: I have tried to clear up the question. The html way was the only idea I had but I get its not a good idea, trying to find proper solution.

Comment: You described it in the most horrible way but I guess what you want is: your customers will enter `<sup>TM</sup>` and you store in database `™`?

Comment: Yes this is what I want, sorry I explained it so bad!

Comment: take a look at htmlentities() and htmlspecialcharacters()

Comment: So basically you want to allow _some_/certain HTML tags, but still deny others (and have them display as pure text instead should they be entered) … do some research in that direction.

Comment: Thanks guys, so far I am using htmlspecialchars to store the inforation then htmlspecialchars_decode to display it, do i need to think about security with this approach?